# VBA Data missing on the copied Pivot Table

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on my VBA code in Excel. The first Pivot Table was generated by VBA and works well. However I need more Pivot Tables based on the same data source with different row or column items. I tried to copy the first Pivot Table to cell L8, however after pasted, the data in the new Pivot Table disappears. When I manually refresh the pivot table, the data comes up again. Here's my code -

```
wsPvtTbl.PivotTables("PivotTable1").TableRange2.Copy Destination:=wsPvtTbl.Range("L8")
```

This is the screen shot of the second Pivot Table
[image]

is there a way to fix? Thanks.

*****Update*****

I tired to refresh pivot tables with following code attached to a different button and it worked. I thought it would be working within the same sub but I'm not sure why it only works separately?

```
ThisWorkbook.refreshall
```

Comment: While this shouldn't be a case, after copying the pivot table use ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll as the next line.

Comment: @sktneer Thank you. I added ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll however the table still remains the same. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Try to clear new pivot table's filters after pasting, i.e.: wsPvtTbl.PivotTables("PivotTable2").ClearAllFilters

Comment: @RADO Thanks. There's an error after I put your code in - "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: I used a made-up name "PivotTable2". You need to replace it with the name of the new pivot table created in "L8".

Comment: @RADO the pivot table will be renamed every time I run the code. My current copied pivot table's name is "PivotTable29" :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this...

```
Sub CopyPivotTable()
Dim wsPvtTbl As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField

Set wsPvtTbl = ActiveSheet

wsPvtTbl.PivotTables("PivotTable1").TableRange2.Copy Destination:=wsPvtTbl.Range("L8")

For Each pt In wsPvtTbl.PivotTables
    If pt.Name <> "PivotTable1" Then            
        For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
            pf.ClearAllFilters
        Next pf
    End If
Next pt
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @sktneer I just noticed that if I run the code line by line (F8), the new pivot table will be shown correctly. However when I press F5 or click the button attached, the table will lose the numbers. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: I tested it and it works for me. Not sure what's happening at your end.

Comment: I added up "ThisWorkbook.refreshall" in another Macro and it worked. However when I put it into the original sub it doesn't work again.